# Одинаковая высота flex-item в независимых flex-container

Tags: css, flexbox

Имеется вот такая конструкция:

```
<section id="main">

    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
        <div class="flex-item"></div>
    </div>

</section>
```

https://codepen.io/dis6/pen/oNgBBwy

`flex-item` может иметь разное кол-во контента, следовательно, высота может меняться. Задача в том, чтобы `flex-item`в обеих колонках (`flex-container)`всегда имели одинаковую высоту, по самому высокому из двух контейнеров. Кол-во `flex-item` в каждом из контейнеров неопределённое.

Возможно ли такое реализовать на css-flexbox?

Пока что решение проблемы вижу в медиа-запросе в проблемном диапазоне ширины экрана, где `flex-item` назначается высота. Загвоздка в том, что я не знаю кол-во контента в итемах, могу лишь предполагать, чего разумеется недостаточно. На смартфоне контейнеры занимают 100% ширины и выстраиваются в колонку, так что проблема отпадает.

Может переверстать на css-grid?

РЕШЕНИЕ:  https://codepen.io/dis6/pen/oNgBBwy

Comment: я правильно понял, что ты хочешь, что бы высота всех итемов равнялось высоте самого высокого в двух колонках?Т.е [вот тут](https://jsfiddle.net/jkLs9ptu/)  все итемы должны иметь высоту такую же как и 3 в первой колонке?

Comment: Да, всё верно. На странице будет 2 колонки с итемами, и ещё сайдбар. В каждую колонку выводится контент разных категорий, поэтому выводятся в разных контейнерах. Моя задача в том, чтобы на планшетных размерах устройства порядок итемов не сыпался в сумбурную конструкцию.
На мониторных разрешениях, и на смартфонах проблемы нет.

Comment: по моему тут без js не обойтись https://jsfiddle.net/np0xg614/

Comment: или я чего то не понял...дай код как ты сделал на мониторных разрешениях.

Comment: Всё правильно понял. Это решает проблему.

Comment: Погоди, я по другому чуть чуть сделаю.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k9zgj8e2/

Comment: Волшебно работает, снимаю шляпу!

Comment: "Моя задача в том, чтобы на планшетных размерах устройства порядок итемов не сыпался в сумбурную конструкцию" - а старые добрые таблицы уже окончательно отменили?

Comment: Разумеется нет. Дело в том, что в каждую колонку выводится контент разных категорий, и вывести разный контент (с фильтрами и прочим) в одну таблицу, где в первую ячейку выводится одна категория, а во вторую другая — ещё большее кастылестроение, чем предложенный человеком скрипт. К тому же колонки на телефоне выстраиваются в столбик, а как это реализовать с помощью таблицы, я, например, ума не приложу.